# Exercise Javascript - Find string appearance and change it

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have been asked this exercise in my coding bootcamp but I have no idea how to do it, would anyone have an idea and explanation?

- Create a string that has the word “not” and “bad” inside
- Create another variable that should find the first appearance of the substring “not” and “bad”.
- If the ‘bad’ follows the “not”, then it should replace the whole “not”…”bad” substring with ‘good’ than console.log the result.
- If it doesn’t find “not” and “bad” in the right sequence (or at all), just console.log the original sentence.

---

This is what I started with:

```
let str1 = "These pasta are not bad"
let str2 =
```

Comment: Welcome!
Do you have some examples of the string to be searched?
Do the "not" and "bad" have to be consecutive as in "This is not bad!"?
Or, can they have words between them such as "Lets play the good cop bad cop on the suspect"?
Consider `slice`, `find`, `includes`...
Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! It can be any string with the "not" and "bad" words. I have just found out how to make it, here the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with two inclusive replace functions:

- using RegExp Match and Split and Join (`inclusiveReplaceRegExpMatchSplitJoin`), or
- using Search, Slice and Concat (`inclusiveReplaceSearchSliceConcat`)

```js
function inclusiveReplaceRegExpMatchSplitJoin(originalString, opennerString, closerString, replacementString) {
  var regExp=new RegExp(opennerString+"(.*)"+closerString);
  var match=originalString.match(regExp);
  return match
    ?originalString.split(match[0]).join(replacementString)
    :originalString
  ;
}

function inclusiveReplaceSearchSliceConcat(originalString, opennerString, closerString, replacementString) {
  var opennerIndex=originalString.search(opennerString);
  var closerIndex=originalString.search(closerString);
  return (opennerIndex!=-1 && closerIndex!=-1 && opennerIndex<closerIndex)
    ?"".concat(
      originalString.slice(0, opennerIndex),
      replacementString,
      originalString.slice(closerIndex+closerString.length)
    )
    :originalString
  ;
}

function justForSnippetLogging(originalString, opennerString, closerString, replacementString) {
  console.log("\""+originalString+"\""+", "+"\""+opennerString+"\""+", "+"\""+closerString+"\""+", "+"\""+replacementString+"\""+" =>");
  console.log("  inclusiveReplaceRegExpMatchSplitJoin:\n    " +inclusiveReplaceRegExpMatchSplitJoin(originalString, opennerString, closerString, replacementString));
  console.log("  inclusiveReplaceSearchSliceConcat:\n    " +inclusiveReplaceSearchSliceConcat(originalString, opennerString, closerString, replacementString));
}

justForSnippetLogging("this food is not at all bad!", "not", "bad", "good");
justForSnippetLogging("this food is bad!", "not", "bad", "good");
justForSnippetLogging("this food is bad, not good!", "not", "bad", "good");
justForSnippetLogging("this is food?", "not", "bad", "good");
justForSnippetLogging("one two three four five", "two", "four", "...");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Note: I've coded functionality for case-insensitive, capitalizing if originalString first letter is capital and it begins with opennerString, making closerString lowerCase, but decided not to use it.

Comment: You are welcome!
Is everything clear/anything you would like me to explain more?
Thank you for accepting my answer!
Two more reputation points and you can up-vote it too!

Comment: Yes, everything is clear to me! Thanks a lot again :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "These pasta are not bad";
var not = /not/i;
var findnot = str.match(not);
var bad = /bad/i;
var findbad = str.match(bad);
console.log(findnot);
console.log(findbad);

var result = str.replace("not bad", "good");
console.log(result);
```